# <iframe> embeded youtube video -seems to work but- stays loading in iphone

Tags: iphone, iframe, youtube

Well is kind of strange,

I can see the embed,

I can click the play button,

The video starts loading,

the video keeps loading and you never get to see the video.

I am using the: http://youtube.com/embed/videoID url and i tried many,

Any idea what i'm missing? this is the markup:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://youtube.com/embed/{videoID}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
```

And can be tested here: http://toniweb.us/vimeo-like/nPlayer.html

Comment: well youtube provides it like that! but will test anyway

Comment: Yep, have had this for the last week or two in apps that use the same code.

Comment: This is not about embedded processing. Retagged

Comment: The issue you have posted about is one that I have also been experiencing lately - that is what I meant. Our network guys at work figured out that one of the ports or channels that Youtube uses to deliver video content was being blocked somewhere on our network. I've just tested your link on my computer and iPhone, and can confirm that it works fine. Maybe it's the connection you are on - can you give us any info about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing the YouTube website on the iPhone and playing any video from there--not within the YouTube app on the iPhone but from the YouTube page in Safari. If that doesn't work then I don't think you can do anything about it, it's some networking or Safari iOS issue. I know that on my iPhone I have never managed to play an embedded YouTube video, doing so gives the issue you describe (stuck in "loading"), for me it only ever works in the YouTube app. Could be due to the network I'm on.

If that's the case you could provide a link to open the video in the YouTube app. See this question on how to achieve this: [Launch Youtube app with a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797613/launch-youtube-app-with-a-video)